# How to use change the following code to work on a device using touch controls?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity and C# to create a game. The following code enables the player to move left and right by using the arrow keys on the computer, but I need it to work on an Andriod device. Is there an easy way to use this code to enable the game to work on an Andriod device by using touch controls and without rewriting all the code?

```
void Start()
{
    myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    myAnim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundCheckRadius, whatIsGround);

    if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") > 0f)
    {
        myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(moveSpeed, 
        myRigidbody.velocity.y, 0);
    }
    else if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") < 0f)
    {
        myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(-moveSpeed, 
        myRigidbody.velocity.y, 0f);
    }
    else
    {
        myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(0f, myRigidbody.velocity.y,0f);
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
    {
        myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(myRigidbody.velocity.x, jumpSpeed, 0f);
    }

    myAnim.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(myRigidbody.velocity.x));
    myAnim.SetBool("Grounded", isGrounded);
    }
}
```

Comment: is it written within unity? bc u can also export this code to work on android from unity.

Comment: No, it's written within visual studios and added as a script to the player

Comment: well of course. unity is a WYSIWYG program. but you can use unity and write c-sharp to deploy to mobile.

Comment: Have a look at the [Mobile Input Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MobileInput.html) and [Input.GetTouch](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html). If you than have a specific coding related question come back here.

Comment: @soldforapp How do I write c-sharp within Unity? I can find something called MonoDevelop? I am new to Unity so I am still learning about it.

Comment: u can use mono develop. download unity, itll walk you through it all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. The three variables (leftBtn, rightBtn and jump) will be triggered accordingly:

1. if touch bottom right of screen, rightBtn = true
2. if touch bottom left of screen, leftBtn = true
3. if touch anywhere on top half of screen, jump = true

-

```
bool leftBtn = false;
bool rightBtn = false;
bool jump = false;

void Update()
{
    leftBtn = false;
    rightBtn = false;
    jump = false;
    if(Input.touches.Length > 0){
        Touch touch = Input.touches [0];
        if (touch.position.y > Screen.height / 2) {
            jump = true;
        } else {
            if (touch.position.x > Screen.width / 2) {
                rightBtn = true;
            } else {
                leftBtn = true;
            }
        }
    }

    //put the rest Of your code here \/
}
```

So I think this would be what this would look like in your code (but I may have got right and left the wrong way around):

```
bool leftBtn = false;
bool rightBtn = false;
bool jump = false;

void Start()
{
    myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    myAnim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    leftBtn = false;
    rightBtn = false;
    jump = false;
    if(Input.touches.Length > 0){
        Touch touch = Input.touches [0];
        if (touch.position.y > Screen.height / 2) {
            jump = true;
        } else {
            if (touch.position.x > Screen.width / 2) {
                rightBtn = true;
            } else {
                leftBtn = true;
            }
        }
    }


    isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundCheckRadius, whatIsGround);

    if (rightBtn)
    {
        myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(moveSpeed, 
            myRigidbody.velocity.y, 0);
    }
    else if (leftBtn)
    {
        myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(-moveSpeed, 
        myRigidbody.velocity.y, 0f);
    }
    else
    {
        myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(0f, myRigidbody.velocity.y,0f);
    }

    if (jump && isGrounded)
    {
        myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(myRigidbody.velocity.x, jumpSpeed, 0f);
    }

    myAnim.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(myRigidbody.velocity.x));
    myAnim.SetBool("Grounded", isGrounded);
}
```

If you want you can play around with  Screen.width / 2  and  Screen.height / 2  to get different areas of the screen triggering different functions.